# is this the proper way to return 2 fields from a DB?

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to get a user by Id through a separate view and controller but in this instance I am trying to get a list of all users and display it to the screen. The problem lies somewhere in the getUserArray function or possibly the getUser function. I am not proficient enough to spot it though. The getUserById function doesnt call getUserArray() or getUser() and it works fine.There are no fields in the DB called "user" as of now its just the 3 fields from the SELECT statement that I want to grab and display.

```
    //UserDB.class.php
    public static function getAll() {
        $query =  "SELECT userId, userFirstName, userLastName 
                      FROM users
                      GROUP BY userId";

        $users = array();
        try {
            $db = Database::getDB ();
            $statement = $db->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute ();
            $users = UserDB::getUserArray($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
            $statement->closeCursor ();
        } catch ( PDOException $e ) { // Not permanent error handling
            echo "<p>Error getting all users ".$e->getMessage()."</p>";
        }
        return $users;
    }

    public static function getUserArray($rowSets) {
        $users = array ();
        foreach ( $rowSets as $userRow ) {
            $user = UserDB::getUser($userRow);
            array_push ( $users, $user );
        }
        return $users;
    }

    public static function getUser($userRow) {
        // Return a comment object from a rowset.
        return new UserData ( $userRow );
    }



//UserData.class.php
// Responsibility: Holds data for comment and performs validation
// Constructor expects an associative array with field values for initialization
<?php
class UserData {
    private $userId;
    private $user;
    private $userFirstName;
    private $userLastName;


    public function __construct($formInput) {
        $this->initialize($formInput);
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getUserFirstName(){
        return $this->userFirstName;
    }

    public function getUserLastName(){
        return $this->userLastName;
    }

    public function getUserId() {
        return $this->userId;
    }


    public function getParameters() {
        // Return data fields as an associative array
        $paramArray = array("userId" => $this->userId,
                            "userFirstName" => $this->userFirstName,
                            "userLastName" => $this->userLastName
                           );
        return $paramArray;
    }

    public function printUser() {
        echo "<h1>SHIELD Member</h1>";
        echo "User Id: $this->userId<br>";
        echo "User first name: $this->userFirstName<br>";
        echo "User last name: $this->userLastName<br>";
    }

    private function initialize($formInput) {
        if (isset($formInput['userId']))
            $this->userId = $formInput['userId'];
        else
            $this->userId = 0;
        if (isset($formInput['userFirstName']))
            $this->userFirstName = $formInput['userFirstName'];
        if (isset($formInput['userLastName']))
            $this->userLastName = $formInput['userLastName'];
    }
}
?>

//UsersController.php
<?php
include_once("../views/showUsers.php");
include_once("../models/UserDB.class.php");
include_once("../models/UserData.class.php");
include_once("../models/Database.class.php");


$myUsers = UserDB::getAll();
showUsers($myUsers, "All users");
?>




//showUsers.php
// Displays a list of all users 
// Input: an array of CommentData objects
<?php
function showUsers($userList, $msg) {
    echo "<h1>".$msg."</h1>";

    foreach ($userList as $user) {
        $user->printUser();
    }

    echo '<h3><a href="../index.php">Back to home</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like most of `getUser()` was commented out, maybe for debugging purposes? Can you please check what is or isn't supposed to be commented out?

Comment: We also maybe need to see the code in context where these methods are called. I can see that `getUserArray()` is called by `getAll()`. Instead of passing the result of `fetchAll()` into `getUserArray()`, execute the statement then `print_r()` the result of `fetchAll()` so you can verify that the SQL returned rows in the `getAll()` method, isolated from everything else.

Comment: What problem are you having? It looks like this code depends on the constructor for the `UserData` class taking an associative array and building the proper `UserData` object from it. Show the constructor.

Comment: I made the additions asked for. The problem, I feel, does lie with the constructor but Im not sure what to change to fix the issue.

Comment: as far as the print all goes, you are saying to put something that looks like this: printr($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); before the call to getUserArray? and will it show up up if I refresh the showUsers.php page?

Comment: Incidentally, your first query includes a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating functions - the implication being that there may be multiple identical userids within the table. However, this cannot be true!